# Symfony App - Doctrine FATAL ERROR - Memory exhausted without trace

Tags: symfony, error-handling, doctrine

I'am receiving sometimes this error:

`Uncaught Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\OutOfMemoryException: "Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 290816 bytes)" at project/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php line 117`
OR

`"project/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:2822"`

But this is all i got, no trace, no nothing. Had anyone got a similar issue? (always 134217728 and tried to allocate 290816 bytes) .

Thank you!

Comment: the slight problem is, that the memory allocation fails *in the debug component*, meaning, it runs out of memory when creating the trace (probably due to a completely different exception, which caused the debug component to start up). However, I would start by increasing the memory limit of php to something greater than 128mb. if you're running this on production, you're doing it wrong (avoid debug on production), on local (=dev) you should allow for more than 128mb like ... 512 maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You must change memory_limit parameter in php.ini, because Doctrine has exhausted the available php memory

Comment: I've configured 8GB RAM to allocate for the process, and yet PHP complaint about RAM exhausted...
Allowed memory size of 8589934592 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)

I believe it's the 20480 bytes issue?